# MultiThreaded INSERTs performance

Tags: java, database, querydsl

Is there any advantage in doing parallel multithreaded `INSERT`s (Java + QueryDSL) on *n* different tables (Oracle 11g) over using the sequential approach? (`INSERT into table1`, .. , `INSERT into tableN`)

(My case is an ETL process executing multiple bulk inserts in different tables)

Comment: Why don't you test it? Looks a fairly easy test and benchmarking. Anyway, on a quick look I would say that parallel INSERTs will be faster. Also you might want to look into JDBC batches and let DB engine take care of best method to do it.